# Data displaying in Overall Code Coverage section in developer console is not consistent

Tags: developer-console, code-coverage, unit-test

The data displaying in Overall Code Coverage section in developer console is not consistent, but displays incorrect code coverage sometimes 100% and sometimes with lesser number. For example, OpenDocumentsController listed in that displays 100% (179/179) though the lines of code in the controller class is 434. When i click the controller from that section and the code coverage is displays as 29% and many lines are red blocked. In the image below it shows as 0% whereas actual class in Apex Classes display 100%. Which one is correct?

Experts please advice

How can i see correct data on Overall Code Coverage section in dev console? 
Is there any other alternative way to run the test classes?
Where else i can ensure the code coverage is correct or not?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, after one year I'm still facing the same problem. Have you gotten any solution?